# SwipeCellKit Swipe to delete not being called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swipe

Hi I am using SwipeCellKit and would like to swipe .right to delete a line at indexPath.row. I have called the function editActionsForRowAt indexPath and have used the code below, but the user is still unable to swipe to delete.

I have the following variables

```
var allLists:[ShoppingList] = []
var isSwipeRightEnabled = false
var defaultOptions = SwipeTableOptions()
```

My code is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {

    if orientation == .left {
        guard isSwipeRightEnabled else { return nil }
    }

    let delete = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: nil) { action, indexPath in

        var list: ShoppingList

        if self.allLists.count > 0 {
            list = self.allLists[indexPath.row]
            self.allLists.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        } else {
            list = self.allLists[indexPath.row]
        }

        list.deleteItemInBackground(shoppingList: list)

        action.fulfill(with: .delete)
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
    configure(action: delete, with: .trash)
    return [delete]

}


func configure(action: SwipeAction, with descriptor: ActionDescriptor) {
    action.title = descriptor.title()
    action.image = descriptor.image()
    action.backgroundColor = descriptor.colour
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsOptionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> SwipeTableOptions {

    var options = SwipeTableOptions()
    options.transitionStyle = defaultOptions.transitionStyle
    options.buttonSpacing = 11
    return options

}
```

I have a helper .swift file called SwipeTableViewHelpers.swift which is this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

enum ActionDescriptor {
case save, returnPurchase, trash

func title() -> String? {

    switch self {
    case .save: return "Save"
    case .returnPurchase: return "Return"
    case .trash: return "Delete"

    }
}

var colour: UIColor {
    switch self {
    case .save: return .lightGray
    case .returnPurchase: return .lightGray
    case .trash: return .red
    }
}

func image() -> UIImage? {

    let name: String
    switch self {
    case .save: name = "saveItem"
    case .returnPurchase: name = "ReturnFilled"
    case .trash: name = "Trash"
    }

    return UIImage(named: name)
}
}

func createSelectedBackgroundView() -> UIView {

let view = UIView()
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
return view
}
```

and the function called to deleteItemInBackground is:

```
func deleteItemInBackground(shoppingList: ShoppingList) {

    let ref = firebase.child(kSHOPPINGLIST).child(FUser.currentId()).child(shoppingList.id)
    ref.removeValue()

}
```

When the user swipes on a tableViewCell nothing happens, can anyone see any reason for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented, you need to set the delegate for the cell:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! SwipeTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jeshua, I have already called this function...                     


`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ListTableViewCell
        let shoppingList = allLists[indexPath.row]
        cell.bindData(item: shoppingList)
        return cell
    }`  

I have a helper file called ListTableViewCell that conforms to SwipeTableViewCell

Comment: `class ListTableViewCell: SwipeTableViewCell {        
    @IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var totalItemsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var totalPriceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var dateLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        

        
    }
    
}`

Comment: You apparently are not setting the delegate property of the cell there which is absolutely critical for any code that uses the delegate pattern. In cellForRowAt: you must set the delegate with `cell.delegate = self` before returning it.

Comment: You are a hero! I wasn't setting the delegate of the cell. Just to clarify, in my cellForRowAt function i added the line of code suggested and it works. Thank you @Jeshua

Answer (score 0):

If you are debugging with ios 11 the you need to implement this method

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *) func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?{ 
let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Delete", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
     success(true)
 })
 deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red
 return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
}
```

else

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {}
```

or you can use bellow method for delete

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {return true}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
  // by deleting you can update tableview
}}
```